# Docker containers keep losing internet

Tags: docker

I have configured to use docker on Centos 6.5. Quite often the containers keep losing internet. In such instances I have to restart Docker on the host. Recently, I tried to run an yum update from inside a container which failed. Following is the log from /var/log/docker

```
2014/07/15 10:33:36 GET /v1.12/containers/update_test/json
[b601ba8c] +job container_inspect(update_test)
[b601ba8c] -job container_inspect(update_test) = OK (0)
2014/07/15 10:33:36 POST /v1.12/containers/update_test/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1
[b601ba8c] +job container_inspect(update_test)
2014/07/15 10:33:36 POST /v1.12/containers/update_test/start
[b601ba8c] +job start(update_test)
[b601ba8c] -job container_inspect(update_test) = OK (0)
[b601ba8c] +job attach(update_test)
[b601ba8c] +job allocate_interface(5a5c0247441ef5872b531ba720ba1f7d8af2df1cbd47b4a98b84a7b995384d8b)
[b601ba8c] -job allocate_interface(5a5c0247441ef5872b531ba720ba1f7d8af2df1cbd47b4a98b84a7b995384d8b) = OK (0)
[b601ba8c] -job start(update_test) = OK (0)
2014/07/15 10:33:36 POST /v1.12/containers/update_test/resize?h=37&w=165
[b601ba8c] +job resize(update_test, 37, 165)
[b601ba8c] -job resize(update_test, 37, 165) = OK (0)
[b601ba8c] +job release_interface(5a5c0247441ef5872b531ba720ba1f7d8af2df1cbd47b4a98b84a7b995384d8b)
[b601ba8c] -job release_interface(5a5c0247441ef5872b531ba720ba1f7d8af2df1cbd47b4a98b84a7b995384d8b) = OK (0)
[error] container.go:492 5a5c0247441ef5872b531ba720ba1f7d8af2df1cbd47b4a98b84a7b995384d8b: Error closing terminal: invalid argument
[b601ba8c] -job attach(update_test) = OK (0)
```

As mentioned above restarting Docker on the host solves the issue. I don't want to keep restarting the docker as I am planning to run a production application through docker. Anybody have any idea in this regard?

Please let me know if you need more information in this regard.

Comment: Have you found any patterns on when you are losing connection? Is it on your laptop? Can you reproduce it on another machine/server? First thought is that there is some network powersave options on your host that messes with the virtual network interfaces that docker needs. Is the output of `ip route list`, `ip addr show` the same before and after this happens?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. I have not found the pattern yet. But this is a good starting point. I have to implement some script inside my container for that. I will update if I found anything in this regard.

Comment: Another thing you might want to check is `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` where docker puts all the rules to actually allow the containers to talk to different parts of then network (between them or out).. Maybe the problem is a firewall tool/helper that wants full control over the iptables rules, and is therefor flushing the docker rules from time to time..

Comment: That's another good point as well. Will keep an eye on that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my bad that I did not mention that the host was hosted in the Rackspace. My apologies for not clarifying that (at that time I thought that it was irrelevant). It was the Rackspace's automated routine that kept messing up the iptables which obviously affected the docker routing. Rackspace did suggest to create a lock file somewhere in the /etc to prevent their automated routine touching the iptables which I have forgotten now; should not be difficult for anybody to get this from them if they experience the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by **Maduraiveeran**, to prevent Rackspace from overwriting Docker's custom iptables rules you need to create a lock file in `/etc`. The file should be named `rackconnect-allow-custom-iptables`:

```sh
touch /etc/rackconnect-allow-custom-iptables
```

Once the lockfile has been created, restart your docker daemon with: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-prevent-rackconnect-from-overwriting-custom-iptables-rules-on-linux-cloud-servers/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set a DNS at the host `/etc/resolv.conf` , then you can face some internet issues; If you still have this issue, consider using the `--dns 209.244.0.3` at your `docker run` settings; the solution might look like this:

`docker run -d --dns 209.244.0.3 centos webapp.sh`

Another useful param you would maybe require at some point in this matter is `--add-host` which adds a host to the containers' `/etc/hosts` file